# Null pointer running SFTP through spring mvc

Tags: java

Null pointer points to these 2 lines

`channelSftp.exit();`

```
res = ftpService.send("c:\\Cache\\opt.xml");






 @RequestMapping("/ftpFileToServer.json")
    public String ftpFiletoServer(ModelMap model) { 
SFTPService ftpService;
    boolean res;
    Result result;

    try {
        ftpService = new SFTPService();
         res = ftpService.send("c:\\Cache\\opt.xml");

         result = new Result(res, null);

        if (result.isSuccess()) {

            GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson gson = builder.create();
            String json = gson.toJson(result);
            model.put("ftpFileToServer", json);
```

The SFTP service works outside when i test it using a driverClass and clicking run. However when using it with spring where i uses it it doesn't work.

preparing the host information for sftp.
An exception was found while transfering the response.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.xxxxx.xxxx.service.SFTPService.send(SFTPService.java:56)
at com.xxxxx.xxxx.controller.BaseController.ftpFiletoServer(BaseController.java:433)




public boolean send(String fileName) {

    props = new Properties();
    String propertiesFilename = "src/main/resources/Properties/sftp.properties";

    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
    System.out.println("preparing the host information for sftp.");
    try {
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFilename));
        String SFTPHOST = props.getProperty("SFTPHOST").trim();
        int SFTPPORT = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("SFTPPORT")
                .trim());
        String SFTPUSER = props.getProperty("SFTPUSER").trim();
        String SFTPPASS = props.getProperty("SFTPPASS").trim();
        String SFTPWORKINGDIR = props.getProperty("SFTPWORKINGDIR").trim();

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
        session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Host connected.");
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        System.out.println("sftp channel opened and connected.");
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
        File f = new File(fileName);
        channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());

        System.out.println("File transfered successfully to host.");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception found while tranfer the response.");
    } finally {

        channelSftp.exit();
        System.out.println("sftp Channel exited.");
        channel.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Channel disconnected.");
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Host Session disconnected.");
    }
    return true;
}
```

StackTrace:

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\Properties\sftp.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
    at com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.service.SFTPService.send(SFTPService.java:27)
    at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.controller.BaseController.ftpFiletoServer(BaseController.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.xxxx.xxxxxx.service.SFTPService.send(SFTPService.java:57)
    at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.controller.BaseController.ftpFiletoServer(BaseController.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Include the stacktrace please.

Comment: According to jcraft api, you dont need to exit channelSftp AND disconnect channel

Comment: Did you made sure that send(fileName) actually gets a filename?

Comment: i just check added another print stack trace, java.io.FileNotFoundException: Looks like the properties file is not being read